# How do I recover my data from a ransomware .rumba?

Tags: virus, virus-removal, ransomware

My laptop got infected with a ransomware. It add extension .rumba to my files. How do recover my data? I've tried all the method in the google first page of "How to remove .rumba" to no avail. I appreciate any help and suggestion.

Comment: If the data is encrypted, you either hope it used broken encryption or restore from backups.  Most malware doesn’t end up having the key exposed allowing the victims to decrypt their data.

Comment: You may need to restore from backup after wiping the drive, or substitute a different drive and install on that drive, then restore on the newly created system.